# scapy sniff only sniffing my pc's data

Tags: python, scapy

I am new to scapy and I am trying out a code but I seem to be having a problem, not sure if it is with the code or with my pc but the code looks something like this :

```
from scapy.all import *

def callback(pkt):
   if pkt.haslayer(TCP):
      print pkt.summary()
      print pkt.show()
      print pkt[TCP] # equivalent to: print pkt.getlayer(TCP)

sniff(filter='port 80', prn=callback, store=0)
```

but when I run the script I seem to be only catching traffic from my computers IP ,  is there a way to catch all traffic on my wifi router with scapy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly.

During normal operations, Scapy (or any packet monitoring program) can only see data going to or from the computer it is on.  There are some ways of re-routing information so they go through your computer, but that's another discussion.  You can use a packet monitoring program to monitor all data on a wifi network if and only if your wireless network card's chipset (or driver) allows you to enter "monitor" or "RFMon" mode.

[Here is a webpage](http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2011/10/13/special-request-wireless-client-sniffing-with-scapy) where someone seems to do exactly what you want.  Again, this only works if you can switch into Montior/RFMon mode first.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have installed aircrack and tried to put my network card in monitor mode it succeeds but then disconnects my wifi adapter, why could this be happening ? It seems to be killing a process called "dhclient" when i run the command

Comment: @Amroelaswar That's normal.  Aircrack will switch your wifi card out of "Managed" and put it in "Monitor" mode.  This means that your wifi card isn't strictly on the wireless network.  It can watch all data that runs across it, but you can't transmit or receive anything directly.  There are a few networking components(such as DHClient) that won't work after you do that.  You may need to get a USB network card if you want to be on a network and monitor a network at the same time.